# Connect oracle database to eclipse

Tags: java, sql, oracle, eclipse

I tried to make a connection with oracle databse and eclipse by using this code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Testsql {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","biline","bl");         
        System.out.println("Connection Successful");}}
```

I download ojdbc6 and i add it as external jar in the libraries, but i got this message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at ProjetGL/ProjetGL.Testsql.main(Testsql.java:7)
```

And when i add ojdbc5 with ojdbc6 i got this(just to try):

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module ojdbc5 contains package oracle.core.lmx, module ojdbc6 exports package oracle.core.lmx to ojdbc5
```

I didn't understand the error message. Please, is there someone here who has any idea about the problem?
I'm working with ubuntu(using an express edition of oracle DB).

Comment: Appears that you are missing the Oracle database driver which is required to make connection to Oracle database.

Comment: That doesn't look like the right class name. Are you sure it is, and that this is the right way to load the driver?

Comment: the o in oracle need to be capitalized, i made 3 days searching for a solution(no matter i learned lot of things), thanks for the response and sorry of this lack of attention.